# core.async toggle channel mix

Tags: clojure, core.async, backpressure

I am experimenting with core.async's mixes. It seems that muting an input channel in a mix would be one of possible ways of implementing backpressure. I am using the code below:

```
(def output-chan (chan))
(def input-chan (chan))
(def mixer (admix (mix output-chan) input-chan))
(toggle mixer {input-chan {:mute true}})
```

Evaluating last line in the REPL gives

`CompilerException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No implementation of method: :toggle* of protocol: #'clojure.core.async/Mix found for class: java.lang.Boolean`.

What is wrong with the above example code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (def mixer (admix (mix output-chan) input-chan))

You assign the return value of `admix` to `mixer`, which is a boolean and not the expected mixer. Try:

```
(def output-chan (chan))
(def input-chan (chan))
(def mixer (mix output-chan))
(admix mixer input-chan)
(toggle mixer {input-chan {:mute true}})
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I think i got confused by the mutability of `mixer`.